# Python deploy on heroku cannot do math.cos()

Tags: python, heroku

I deploy my python program on Heroku for my api.ai robot's cosine calculation. However, after I get a value for cos and put the value inside the `math.cos(value)` function, api.ai will give
`"errorDetails": "Webhook call failed. Error: Webhook response was empty."`

But the program will return webhook response if I do not use `math.cos()`.

Code for the calculation:

```
def trig():
req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)
result = req.get("result")
parameters = result.get("parameters")
number = parameters.get("number")
trig_sign = parameters.get("Trigonometry")
number = float(number)
if trig_sign == "Cos":
    out = "The answer is "+ str(math.cos(number)) +" !"
speechText = out
displayText = out
print("Response:")
print(out)
return {
    "speech": speechText,
        "displayText": displayText,
        "source": "pas-robot-math-calculator"
    }
```

Program will work if I do not put math.cos()

```
def trig():
req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)
result = req.get("result")
parameters = result.get("parameters")
number = parameters.get("number")
trig_sign = parameters.get("Trigonometry")
number = float(number)
    #I did not put math.cos() here
    out = "The answer is !"
speechText = out
displayText = out
print("Response:")
print(out)
return {
    "speech": speechText,
        "displayText": displayText,
        "source": "pas-robot-math-calculator"
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I imported math library

Comment: I also used heroku run python to run math.cos(), and it will work.